# What is the fastest way to find data in a .Net dataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have some TXT files which i load in DataTables ( in c# / .Net)
So...my DataTable isn't binded to a "real" database like Oracle or SQL.

Now...i have to find some values in my dataTable.
For the moment i simply use a for loop...The problem is i have large file and it's totally a waste of time.

I cannot use a Dictionnary because of duplicates keys..so, personnaly i want to continue to ue my DataTable.

If i'm not wrong, using LINQ is like using a for no ? It won't help me to gain time no?

So...i was thinking about binding a Dataview to my DataTable and creating my own index...What do you think ? Is it a good idea ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: `DataTable.Select(string filterExpression)`? But if performance becomes an issue, creating a `DataView` with an index seems wise.

Comment: upvote @EdPlunkett comment. However, how you need to use that index matters. Read [DataView Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669089(v=vs.110).aspx). In there are links on filtering and sorting using LINQ-to-DataSet.

Comment: Check out [`LookUp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks).  Quote: *A Lookup<TKey, TElement> resembles a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>. The difference is that a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> maps keys to single values, whereas a Lookup<TKey, TElement> maps keys to collections of values.*

Comment: How big are your text files? Perhaps you should use a search engine like Lucene.NET.

Comment: Hello, thanks, will try Datatable.select, but how using a "TRIM" in the FilterExpression please ? Thanks

Comment: Hello, i tried the Selec() method of DataTable and....it's more long than iterate ! So, have to try with index and dataview i think !